# Case statement to remove columns before today's date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use a `case` statement that will change any rows that have a date previous to today's date and return these rows as `' '` value and then format the date as `dd/MM/yyy hh:mm`

I have tried using this:

```
CASE
    WHEN AppointmentDate1 > getdate() THEN ' '
    WHEN AppointmentDate1 IS NULL THEN ' '
    ELSE AppointmentDate1
END AS [Appointment]
```

But when I run the query I get this error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How do I make this work? And then how do I change to desired format? (`AppointmentDate1` is currently in SQL format, e.g. `'2019-05-22 10:00:00'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value.  It evaluates all the return clauses and chooses the one based on precedence.  Dates have a higher precedence than strings, so your failure is because `' '` (a space) cannot be converted to a date.

If you want a date as the result, then use `NULL`.  In this case, you could do:

```
(CASE WHEN AppointmentDate1 < getdate() THEN AppointmentDate1
 END) AS Appointment
```

If you want a string, then convert to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN AppointmentDate1 < getdate()
      THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AppointmentDate1, 121) 
      ELSE ''  -- I would just use an empty string 
 END) AS [Appointment]
```

I chose style 121.  You might have another style that you like.  Or use `FORMAT()`.